# How to create loops for ordering vectors

Tags: c

I have a homework problem that asks for my code to read a 10-length vector, order it in ascendant order and then print it. I'm trying to do this using a variable int k as a countable index, where the code verifies whether a particular position in the vector is greater than the other positions, and adds 1 to k for each smaller variable. Then, I create a second vector, and atrribute for its kth position this value of the first vector.
The compilation isn't pointing out any mistakes. The code runs, I inform the 10 values of the vector, then it returns a big number and crashes.
Could anyone help me? Thanks in advance.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <locale.h>

int main ()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Portuguese");
    //creates two double vectors
    double v[10], w[10];
    //creates a int variable to be a countable index
    int k = 0;
    //asks for the user to inform the values of the vector
    for (int i=0; i<=9; i++)
    {
        printf("Digite um número:\n");
        scanf("%lf", &v[i]);
    }
    //Here, I create this loop to verify whether each position of the vector v is greater than the other positions.
    for (int j=9; j>=0; j--)
    {
        //For the case j=9, I verify if it is greater than all the predecessor values, and add 1 to k for each case
        if (j==9)
        {
            for (int t=j-1; t>=0; t--)
            {
                if (v[j]>v[t])
                {
                    k+=1;
                }
            }
            //I attribute this value of v to the kth position of the new vector, and restart the countable index
            w[k]=v[j];
            k=0;
            continue;
        }
        //I do the same for the case in which j=0, verifying whether it is greater than the subsequent values
        else if (j==0)
        {
            for (int s=j+1; s<=9; s++)
            {
                if (v[j]>v[s])
                {
                    k+=1;
                }
            }
            w[k]=v[j];
            k=0;
            continue;
        }
        //For all the other values of the vector, I test both whether they are greater than the
        //predecessors and the subsequent values, and add 1 to k for each case
        else
        {
            for (int t=j-1; t>=0; t--)
            {
                if (v[j]>v[t])
                {
                    k+=1;
                }
            }
            for (int s=j+1; s<=9; s--)
            {
                if (v[j]>v[s])
                {
                    k+=1;
                }
            }
            //I attribute this value to the kth position of the new vector and restart the countable index
            w[k]=v[j];
            k=0;

        }
    //Here my loop ends
    }
    //I print the new vector
    for (int p=0; p<=9; p++)
    {
        printf(" %lf ",w[p]);
    }
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Yes, ascending order, sorry

Comment: Would it be cheating to call `qsort` from stdlib?

Comment: Yes hahahahahahhaha

Answer (score 0):

`for (int s=j+1; s<=9; s--)` should have `s++`. I don't see anything else wrong but I'll check with `gdb` if that doesn't fix it.

Comment: Edge case to test: repeated values in the input list.

Comment: Good hint, it worked!!! Thanks a lot, that was annoying me for a long time. Got my vote.

Comment: `k` is the number of smaller values in the array so input v{0,1,2,3,4,5,5,5,5,5} will have w{0,1,2,3,4,5,,,,}, right?